# Как реализовать такой нестандартный слайдер?

Tags: javascript, html, css, карусель, слайдер

Есть задача реализовать нестандартный(для меня) слайдер
Выглядеть должен вот так -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- один слайд.
  И другой слайд -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е., меняется только картинка в "мониторе" и текст. Но не картинка самого монитора.

Проект собран на Ангуляре(если это важно).
Вопрос такой: что здесь лучше использовать чтобы не перебирать кучу плагинов? 
Или нужно ручное решение?
С JS дружу немного.

Comment: Как к вас реализован сам монитор? Если не как то что сложно? Обычный слайдер, любой, можно например slick.

Comment: Делайте маленьким главный блок слайда, подгоняйте его на место монитора, делайте рядом блок с текстом и передавайте по индексу класс active

Comment: Игра - найди отличия. Вы видите разницу между первым скрином и вторым? Я - не вижу.